# How to add a GeoJSON to a map with Leaflet

Tags: javascript, html

I need to add a GeoJSON of a shape to a map using Leaflet.

My code:

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([43.42851395329958, -3.668450798388781], 23);

var geojsonFeature = {
   "type":"Feature",
   "geometry":{"type":"MultiLineString","coordinates":[[[445886.845,4808681.6768],[445887.5215,4808682.5332]]]},
   "properties":{"id":"nudo_153-acometida","x1":445886.8449913647,"y1":4808681.676796015,"x2":445887.52153996995,"y2":4808682.533211502,"longitud":1.091405287449764,"agrupadora":"AGR_AC BT RZ25 P","conductor":"RZ 0,6\/1 kV 3x25+54,6 Alm","ct":"946582","elemento_c":"CABLE","feeder":"33882643","imax":100.0,"nudofin":"acometida","nudoorigen":"nudo_153","numcircuit":3.0,"posicion":"final","r":1.2,"tension":400.0,"tipo":"aereo","tipo_actua":"extension","tipo_eleme":"acometida","tipo_tendi":"posado","tipotramo":"bajada","x":0.1},
   "id":"red_extension.3"
 };
 var myStyle = {
 "color": "yellow",
 "weight": 6,
 "opacity": 1
 };

 L.geoJSON(geojsonFeature, {
   style: myStyle
 }).addTo(map);

 var circle = L.circle([43.42851395329958, -3.668450798388781], {
 color: 'red',
 fillColor: '#f03',
 fillOpacity: 0.5,
 radius: 100
}).addTo(map);

 var wmsLayer = L.tileLayer.wms("http://ovc.catastro.meh.es/Cartografia/WMS/ServidorWMS.aspx?", {
    layers: "Catastro",//nombre de la capa (ver get capabilities)
    format: 'image/jpeg',
  transparent: true,
  maxZoom: 19,
    version: '1.1.1',//wms version (ver get capabilities)
    attribution: "DIRECCION GENERAL DEL CATASTRO"
 });  

wmsLayer.addTo(map);
```

The result is as follows:

[image]

Why is the GeoJSON not showing on my map?

Comment: Have you checked that the geometry is inside your map view?

Comment: Looks like your GeoJSON coordinates aren't in lon,lat. Although the GeoJSON spec states that they can be in other coordinate systems - you will need to explicitly state which one. You also need to consider using the Proj4Leaflet plugin.